# how to send a file with flutter_email_sender?

Tags: flutter

The user has to pick a pdf or word doc and send it via gmail.

On emulator after picking file by clicking send button(gmail app is opened and I can send the file I selected). However,in real phone i repeat the same aproach ,but send button does not work(gmail app is not opened).It does not work.

What can I do?How to solve this problem? In pub dev there is no enough information

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.dart';

class VacancyController extends GetxController {
  final Rx<File?> _file = Rx<File?>(null);
  Rx<bool> isLoading = false.obs;
  File? get file => _file.value;

  Future selectFile() async {
    isLoading.value = true;
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      allowMultiple: false,
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['pdf', 'doc'],
    );
    if (result == null) {
      isLoading.value = false;
      return;
    }
    File takenFile = File(result.files.single.path!);
    _file.value = takenFile;
    isLoading.value = false;
  }

  Future<String> sendFile() async {
    if (file != null) {
      final Email email = Email(
        body: 'CV- faylı bizimlə paylaşın!',
        subject: 'Vakansiya',
        recipients: ['ahmadovf@box.az'],
        // cc: ['cc@example.com'],
        // bcc: ['bcc@example.com'],
        attachmentPaths: [file!.path.toString()],
        isHTML: false,
      );

      await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
      _file.value = null;
      return 'success';
    }
    return 'fail';
  }
}
```

you can have a look to my code.And also I want to share my android manifest file with you.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flutter_emiland">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
      <data android:scheme="mailto" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app opens http url  -->
    <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
  </intent>
   <!-- If your app opens https url  -->
    <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
</queries>
   <application
        android:label="Prol"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried several ways but unable to do it.

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? Do you get an error? The application freezes? The phone displays warnings? If the question is unclear you'll only get fake ChatGPT-generated answers and waste time trying to find out why these fail

Comment: I am sorry for asking unclear question sir.On emulator after picking file by clicking send button(gmail app is opened and I can send the file I selected).However,in real phone i repeat the same aproach ,but send button does not work(gmail app is not opened).There is no error.I tried to use the approach below.Unfortunately it did not help me.What can be a problem? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Add that information in the question itself. `it did not help me` of course it didn't, it's a fake answer. That's why such answers are banned: [Temporary policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1). Someone is either trolling or rep-farming